# Elasticsearch: create alias with routing and filter using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to send this request using Java API:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9201/living/_alias/living_team' -d '
{
  "routing": "living_team",
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "user": "living_team"   //user property must exists 
    }
  }
}'
```

Up to now, I've not been able to figure out how exactly build the Java request:

```
this.elasticsearchResources.getElasticsearchClient()
    .admin()
    .indices()
    .prepareAliases()
    .addAlias(
        ElasticsearchRepository.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX,
        alias,
        QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", alias);
```

This line only creates an ADD ALIAS request with a filter, nevertheless I don't know how to set routing path...

How could I set the routing path up on request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how to set "http://localhost:9201/living/_alias/living_team" on your request?

PS. I wrote this as an answer cause i cannot comment yet.

Edited:

Hope this can help you

```
IndicesAliasesRequest request = new IndicesAliasesRequest();

request.addAliasAction(new AliasAction(AliasAction.Type.ADD).alias("the_alias").index(index).searchRouting("the_search_routing").indexRouting("the_index_routing"));
IndicesAliasesResponse response = elasticsearchClient.admin().indices().aliases(request).get();
```

Comment: I meant how to set routing path information in whichever `java alias creation request`.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it works for you. Thanks